# Can we convert a torch tensor to a numpy array using GPU for faster performance?

Tags: numpy, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

Is it possible to convert a torch tensor to a numpy array using the GPU for faster performance? Currently, I am using `input = input.cpu().detach().numpy()` to convert the tensor to a numpy array on the CPU. Is there a way to utilize the GPU to perform this conversion instead, potentially saving time?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Transferring the tensor from GPU memory to system memory accounts for most of the time consumed. This is limited by the hardware.

The process of converting a tensor that is already in system memory to a numpy array is thoroughly optimized, and the time it takes is negligible. Moreover, the numpy array and the tensor [share their storage](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.numpy.html).